# NameError occurs when running program, how to fix it?

Tags: python

Basically, my code creates different fractals and displays them on a canvas. But when I went to run the program this error message popped up:(class SierpinskiTriangle(Fractal):NameError: name 'Fractal' is not defined). I know this specific error occurs when a variable isn't defined or isn't defined right but I can't find where the problem is. Any help?

```
from tkinter import *
from math import sqrt, sin, cos, pi as PI
from random import randint

# the 2D point class    
class Point(object):
    def __init__(self, x=0.0, y=0.0):
        self.x = float(x)
        self.y = float(y)

# Accessors and mutators
    @property
    def x(self):
        return self._x
    @x.setter
    def x(self, value):
        self._x = value

    @property
    def y(self):
        return self._y

    @y.setter
    def y(self, value):
        self._y = value

# Functions used to calculate the distance and the midpoint
    def dist(self, a):
        return sqrt ((self.x-a.x)**2+(self.y-a.y)**2)

    def midpt(self, a):
        return Point((self.x+a.x)/2, (self.y+a.y)/2)
    
# The magic function
    def magic(self, a, triangle):
        trianglex = triangle
        if (self.x > a.x):
            trianglex = 1.0 - triangle
        triangley = triangle
        if (self.y > a.y):
            triangley = 1.0 - triangle
        x = abs(self.x - a.x) * trianglex + min(self.x, a.x)
        y = abs(self.y - a.y) * triangley + min(self.y, a.y)
        return Point(x,y)

# Function used to define the string
    def __str__(self):
        return "({}, {})".format(self.x, self.y)
    
# the coordinate system class: (0,0) is in the top-left corner
# inherits from the Canvas class of Tkinter
class ChaosGame(Canvas):
    def __init__(self, master):
        Canvas.__init__(self, master, bg="white")
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
        
# sets the dimensions and the radius, as well as the color
        self.dimensions = {"MIN_X":2, "MAX_X":WIDTH-9, "MIN_Y":2, "MAX_Y":HEIGHT-9}
        self.dimensions["MID_Y"] = (self.dimensions["MIN_Y"]+self.dimensions["MAX_Y"])/2
        self.dimensions["MID_X"] = (self.dimensions["MIN_X"]+self.dimensions["MAX_X"])/2
        self.vertexRadius = 1
        self.vertexColor = "blue"
        self.pointRadius = 0
        self.pointColor = "black"
    

# Function used to plot the generated points for the SierpinskiTriangle
    def plot_Values(self, points):
        if(points == "SierpinskiTriangle"):
            p1 = SierpinskiTriangle(self.dimensions)
            for vertex in p1.vertices:
                self.plot_point(vertex, self.vertexColor, self.vertexRadius)
            p = p1.vertices[randint(0, len(p1.vertices)-1)]
            for i in range(p1.num_points):
                p = p.magic(p1.vertices[randint(0, len(p1.vertices)-1)], p1.triangle)
                self.plot_point(p, self.pointColor, self.pointRadius)
                        

# Creates the rest of the fractal classes
        if(points == "Pentagon"):
            p1 = Pentagon(self.dimensions)
            for vertex in p1.vertices:
                self.plot_point(vertex, self.vertexColor, self.vertexRadius)
            p = p1.vertices[randint(0, len(p1.vertices)-1)]
            for i in range(p1.num_points):
                p = p.interpt(p1.vertices[randint(0, len(p1.vertices)-1)], p1.triangle)
                self.plot_point(p, self.pointColor, self.pointRadius)

        if(points == "Hexagon"):
            p1 = Hexagon(self.dimensions)
            for vertex in p1.vertices:
                self.plot_point(vertex, self.vertexColor, self.vertexRadius)
            p = p1.vertices[randint(0, len(p1.vertices)-1)]
            for i in range(p1.num_points):
                p = p.interpt(p1.vertices[randint(0, len(p1.vertices)-1)], p1.triangle)
                self.plot_point(p, self.pointColor, self.pointRadius)                        
                        
        if(points == "Octagon"):
            p1 = Octagon(self.dimensions)
            for vertex in p1.vertices:
                self.plot_point(vertex, self.vertexColor, self.vertexRadius)
            p = p1.vertices[randint(0, len(p1.vertices)-1)]
            for i in range(p1.num_points):
                p = p.interpt(p1.vertices[randint(0, len(p1.vertices)-1)], p1.triangle)
                self.plot_point(p, self.pointColor, self.pointRadius)

        if(points == "SierpinskiCarpet"):
            p1 = SierpinskiCarpet(self.dimensions)
            for vertex in p1.vertices:
                self.plot_point(vertex, self.vertexColor, self.vertexRadius)
            p = p1.vertices[randint(0, len(p1.vertices)-1)]
            for i in range(p1.num_points):
                p = p.interpt(p1.vertices[randint(0, len(p1.vertices)-1)], p1.triangle)
                self.plot_point(p, self.pointColor, self.pointRadius)


# Function used to set the color of the points and used to find the radius
    def plot_point(self, point, color, radius):
        self.create_oval(point.x , point.y , point.x + 2*radius, point.y + 2*radius, outline= color , fill= color)

# Code for the fractals
class SierpinskiTriangle(Fractal):
    def __init__(self, canvas):
        Fractal.__init__(self, canvas)
        v1 = Point(self.dimensions["MID_X"], self.dimensions["MIN_Y"])
        v2 = Point(self.dimensions["MIN_X"], self.dimensions["MAX_Y"])
        v3 = Point(self.dimensions["MAX_X"], self.dimensions["MAX_Y"])
        self.vertices = [ v1, v2, v3 ]

class SierpinskiCarpet(Fractal):
    def __init__(self, canvas):
        Fractal.__init__(self, canvas)
        v1 = Point(self.dimensions["MIN_X"], self.dimensions["MIN_Y"])
        v2 = Point(self.dimensions["MID_X"], self.dimensions["MIN_Y"])
        v3 = Point(self.dimensions["MIN_X"], self.dimensions["MIN_Y"])
        v4 = Point(self.dimensions["MIN_X"], self.dimensions["MID_Y"])
        v5 = Point(self.dimensions["MIN_X"], self.dimensions["MID_Y"])
        v6 = Point(self.dimensions["MIN_X"], self.dimensions["MAX_Y"])
        v7 = Point(self.dimensions["MID_X"], self.dimensions["MAX_Y"])
        v8 = Point(self.dimensions["MIN_X"], self.dimensions["MAX_Y"])
        self.vertices = [ v1, v2, v3, v4, v5, v6, v7, v8 ]
        self.num_points = 100000
        self.traingle = 0.66

class Pentagon(Fractal):
    def __init__(self, canvas):
        Fractal.__init__(self, canvas)
        v1 = Point(self.dimensions["MID_X"] + self.dimensions["MID_X"] * cos(2 * PI / 5 + 60), (self.frac_y(0.5375) + self.dimensions["MID_Y"] * sin(2 * PI / 5 + 60)))
        v2 = Point(self.dimensions["MID_X"] + self.dimensions["MID_X"] * cos(4 * PI / 5 + 60), (self.frac_y(0.5375) + self.dimensions["MID_Y"] * sin(4 * PI / 5 + 60)))
        v3 = Point(self.dimensions["MID_X"] + self.dimensions["MID_X"] * cos(6 * PI / 5 + 60), (self.frac_y(0.5375) + self.dimensions["MID_Y"] * sin(6 * PI / 5 + 60)))
        v4 = Point(self.dimensions["MID_X"] + self.dimensions["MID_X"] * cos(8 * PI / 5 + 60), (self.frac_y(0.5375) + self.dimensions["MID_Y"] * sin(8 * PI / 5 + 60)))
        v5 = Point(self.dimensions["MID_X"] + self.dimensions["MID_X"] * cos(10 * PI / 5 + 60), (self.frac_y(0.5375) + self.dimensions["MID_Y"] * sin(10 * PI / 5 + 60)))
        self.vertices = [ v1, v2, v3, v4, v5 ]
        self.triangle = 0.618

class Hexagon(Fractal):
    def __init__(self, canvas):
        Fractal.__init__(self, canvas)
        v1 = Point(self.dimensions["MID_X"], self.dimensions["MIN_Y"])
        v2 = Point(self.dimensions["MIN_X"], self.frac_y(0.25))
        v3 = Point(self.dimensions["MAX_X"], self.frac_y(0.25))
        v4 = Point(self.dimensions["MIN_X"], self.frac_y(0.75))
        v5 = Point(self.dimensions["MAX_X"], self.frac_y(0.75))
        v6 = Point(self.dimensions["MID_X"], self.dimensions["MAX_Y"])
        self.vertices = [ v1, v2, v3, v4, v5, v6 ]
        self.triangle = 0.665
        
class Octagon(Fractal):
    def __init__(self, canvas):
        Fractal.__init__(self, canvas)
        v1 = Point(self.frac_x(0.2925), self.dimensions["MIN_Y"])
        v2 = Point(self.frac_x(0.7075), self.dimensions["MIN_Y"])
        v3 = Point(self.dimensions["MIN_X"], self.frac_y(0.2925))
        v4 = Point(self.dimensions["MAX_X"], self.frac_y(0.2925))
        v5 = Point(self.dimensions["MIN_X"], self.frac_y(0.7075))
        v6 = Point(self.dimensions["MAX_X"], self.frac_y(0.7075))
        v7 = Point(self.frac_x(0.2925), self.dimensions["MAX_Y"])
        v8 = Point(self.frac_x(0.7075), self.dimensions["MAX_Y"])
        self.vertices = [ v1, v2, v3, v4, v5, v6, v7, v8 ]
        self.num_points = 75000
        self.triangle = 0.705
        
##############################
######## MAIN CODE############      
# sets the size of the canvas 
WIDTH = 700
HEIGHT = 550
# the implemented fractals
Fractals = ["SierpinskiTriangle", "SierpinskiCarpet", "Pentagon", "Hexagon", "Octagon"]

# create the fractals in individual (sequential) windows
for i in Fractals:  
    window = Tk()
    window.geometry("{}x{}".format(WIDTH, HEIGHT))
    window.title("The Chaos Game")
# create the chaos game as a Tkinter canvas inside the window
    s = ChaosGame(window)
# plot some random points
    s.plot_Values(i)
# wait for the window to close
    window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Show us the full error traceback.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/willi/OneDrive/Program 5.py", line 127, in <module>
    class SierpinskiTriangle(Fractal):
NameError: name 'Fractal' is not defined

Comment: Ask yourself, where is the Fractal class defined?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. For debugging help, you need to make a [mre] including minimal code and the [full error message with traceback](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146/4518341). For more tips, see [How to ask a good question](/help/how-to-ask). FWIW, I didn't read all your code, but I skimmed it and didn't see where Fractal is defined. Is it supposed to be imported in `from tkinter import *`? I don't know tkinter myself.

Comment: @Makayla Please [edit] to add that. Comments don't support fancy formatting.

Comment: `class SierpinskiTriangle(Fractal):` is trying to _inherit_ from `Fractal`, not asking a `Fractal` as input. Maybe you forgot to import it?

Comment: Yes, I completely forgot to put it in afterward, I had deleted it earlier to fix another part of the program. So sorry for the waste of time

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your code:

```py
class SierpinskiTriangle(Fractal):
```

This is trying to define the `SierpinskiTriangle` class as a derived class from `Fractal`.

You do not define (or import) `Fractal` at any point in that code, which is why you're getting the error.

Hence the solution is to either define or import the `Fractal` class, before you attempt to sub-class it.